# PyTorch: concat and flatten inputs of different shape

Tags: python, pytorch, concatenation

I have multiple inputs of different shape: `(7,), (), (6,)`, how can I concatenate and flatten them to a single flatten input. My desired output shape is `(14,)`.

For example: `arr1= [1, 2, 3], arr2=6, arr3=[6,7], output=[1,2,3,6,6,7]`. Although I can use multiple numpy.append, but that would be ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `torch.cat`:

```
import torch

arr1 = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = torch.tensor([6])
arr3 = torch.tensor([6,7])

torch.cat((arr1,arr2,arr3))
>>> tensor([1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7])
```